# Jquery: Option selected not work in rendered select list

Tags: php, jquery, renderer, selectedindex

I had a [countries/state chained select box](http://www.iamrohit.in/countries-states-and-cities-database-of-world-in-mysql/) pulled from database **(rendered select list)**, however I want the specific option value remain selected when the page is redirected back by certain action. The user input fields are temporarily stored in `SESSION`, all fields is able to retained the value, excepted `Country` and `State` field.

I couldn't find these pulled `option` tag (which is rendered) appeared in view-sources, but I can view it in Chrome console and Firebug, thus I believe jquery cannot find the particular option value to perform the action, whereas when I hard-code the options, the below script is working:

**Append options**

```
function ajaxCall() {
    this.send = function(data, url, method, success, type) {
        type = type||'json';
        var successRes = function(data) {
            success(data);
        };

        var errorRes = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            alert("Error found \nError Code: "+e.status+" \nError Message: "+e.statusText);
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: successRes,
            error: errorRes,
            dataType: type,
            timeout: 60000
        });

    }
}

function locationInfo() {
    //var rootUrl = "http://lab.iamrohit.in/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/api.php";
    var rootUrl = jsbaseurl + '/inc/api-get-location.php';
    var call = new ajaxCall();

    /* disabled get cities
    this.getCities = function(id) {
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCities&stateId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select city");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.cities').append(option);
                });
                $(".cities").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };
*/
    this.getStates = function(id) {
        $(".states option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getStates&countryId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select state");
            if(data.tp === 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.states').append(option);
                });
                $(".states").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

    this.getCountries = function() {
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCountries';
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select country");
            console.log(data);
            if(data.tp === 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.countries').append(option);
                });
                $(".countries").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

}

$(function() {
    var loc = new locationInfo();
    loc.getCountries();

    $(".countries").on("change", function(ev) {
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        if(countryId !== ''){
        loc.getStates(countryId);
        }
        else{
            $(".states option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });

    /* Disabled city
    $(".states").on("change", function(ev) {
        var stateId = $(this).val();
        if(stateId != ''){
        loc.getCities(stateId);
        }
        else{
            $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
    */
});
```

**Jquery to retain selected option**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('selCountry', '<?php echo $cust_country_code ?>');
    $('.countries').find('option').each(function(i,e){
        if($(e).val() == localStorage.getItem('selCountry')){
            $('.countries').prop('selectedIndex',i);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**the `$cust_country_code` is return countries id that

**HTML** - Options is rendered from db + jquery.

```
<select name="co_country" class="countries">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>

    <!-- HARDCODED FOR TEST, WORKING!
    <option value="111">Brazil</option>
    <option value="142">Germany</option>
    <option value="123">Austria</option>
    <option value="145">Japan</option>
    -->

</select>
```

I was included `$(document).ready()` in order jquery to run while DOM is loaded, but no luck, any workaround?

Comment: where is your code to append `option`? You have to write this after `ajax` `Success` and `html` `appended`. Not in `DOM`.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Good catch!